# Xamarin Forms app re-architechture due to memory leak(s)

Tags: c#, listview, memory, architecture, xamarin.forms

Suppose I've got something like following

1. bunch of Data classes
2. bunch of List of most of the data classes
3. loads of List<List<List<Data>>> classes to represent at least 3D arrays
4. a good few App.MyViewModel view models used in different pages due to thread access
5. the viewmodels are quite complex to my liking with tonnes of properties linking back to point 3
6. in the end, each ListView template is created from ObservableCollection<String> generated from one of the List<Data>

During the lifecycle, those lists might be re**new**ed many times, which I would hope should recycle previous used memory? The list view rows/cells are created as Grids. 
On small list views of up to tens of rows it works good and fast, not increasing memory use too much.
However, on large data sets, containing thousands of rows, even scrolling the ListView sometimes just crashes the app and memory increases dramatically with each portion of data.
So the question really Is, from your own experience, what would you recommend in troubleshooting and perhaps redesigning of the approach?

Comment: Reinstanciating a List or an object in C# does not recycle its memory. It creates a completely new Instance in memory and leaves the old data for the Garbage Collector to free the memory.

Comment: That's fine with me. :) When profiling app, I can see GC kicking in and doing something, but apparently not enough, because memory usage keeps growing. So one of the ways I was thinking to tackle this a hard way is to force GC at some stage to free up all my view models on the App. But reading online doesn't feel that as great idea.

Comment: @yrest well needing to forcing gc blocks threads, and is usually the sign of something else is wrong, however it might help illuminate whats going on a bit more while your are tracking down your problem

Comment: What do your actual rows / cells look like and do they contain images? Least in my experience, incorrect image sizes are the most common issue on memory problems.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I'm profiling more and ditching the idea of GC enforcement, you're right.

Comment: @tjugg that's a great point - what I have in ListView is just bunch of Label and Entry cells. Turns out the entry don't work too well and I also need to use date and time pickers as well as some other entry type controls. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Direct extension of the original question - what is Your personal experience and approach on exception (global) handling? What happens for me is even with try/catch everywhere down the stack, the app crashes triggering OS JIT debugging and I don't understand whether it is OS setting somewhere or development misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look at the *Xamarin Profiler*

[Xamarin Profiler](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/profiler/)

> The Xamarin Profiler has a number of instruments available for
>   profiling Allocations, Cycles, and Time Profiler

There could be so many problems its impossible to know where to start, as for design once again its hard to know how to refactor your app because we don't know what you are trying to achieve. If you need to use lists you need to use them and there isn't much you can do about it.

However, you need to start from *first principles* and make sure you are doing only what you need to do, instantiating only what you need to instantiate, keeping your *xaml* and *UI* with the minimal amount of *cyclic calculations* as possible. Last of all making sure your view models and objects are going out of scope and being garbage collected

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's a good suggestion, will take a look at it. My only problem with that is "Visual Studio Enterprise is required for profiling". So far I have used VS Performance Profiler and Diagnostic Tools, but could not figure out how to pinpoint what exactly consumes so much memory.

Comment: Michael, the last sentence of your answer, I think, points to the start of the root of some of the side issues. Initially we were going to avoid dependency injections and store all relevant info directly in the "root" view model(s) to have easy access and ready availability, but it turns out you have to pay higher price for "more convenient services". ... But I would imagine, it still should be stable enough with the right hardware available. E.g. in case of UWP app it hardly uses 512 MB of RAM when crashing, with 16 GB available. Is it .Net or Xamarin I'm braking with bad code? :) Rhetorical.

Comment: Yeah its hard to tell exactly the smells and issues without seeing the project. however you do need to follow your noes. pinpont the issues. knowing xamarin forms can be hard to time and not like a wpf or desktop app